# drupal6 updaitng the date module

Tags: module, drupal-6, updates

When looking at the update.php I get this error.

**date module can not be updated. Its schema version is 5104. Updates up to and including 5210 have been removed in this release. In order to update date module, you will first need to upgrade to the last version in which these updates were available.**

how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You should download and install version 6.x.2.4 of the module, run update.php and then install the latest version of the module, and run again update.php.

Previous versions are available by clicking at the "View all releases" link at the bottom of the [project page](https://drupal.org/project/date).